# Where is Alira's encampment?

Tags: path-of-exile

I want to find Alira's encampment (Act II, Bandit Lords quest), but in the quest description says

> (...) Alira can be found to the west of the Forest Encampment through the Gloomwoods. (...)

But I can't see any place called "Gloomwoods" in the map.

So in which part of the western Act II map shall I find her encampment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alira can be found in [The Western Forest](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/The_Western_Forest). If you are having trouble, try roaming around the edges of the map - you should eventually find her encampment.

http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Alira

Answer (score 5):

Alira is in The Western Forest. An easy way to find her is to go down the main path, and look at the minimap for where the path has a crack in it, this crack connects another path which will lead you straight to her.